# How to remove First word after closing a tag with jquery

Tags: jquery

Please help me to remove the first word of after closing a tag.

Below is whole HTML markup. Here, I want to remove only "ückeLüneburg" text that is after closing a tag and remaining text will remain the same.

```
<p class="more-content" style="display: block;">
    Am 25.10.2017 lädt das Netzwerk
    <a class="more-content-link" href="#" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">#Link</a>
    ückeLüneburg ein zur Veranstaltung
</p>
```

Is this possible with jquery?

Comment: What have *you* tried? Where did it go wrong? *How* did it go wrong, what happened?

Comment: Are you talking about the `a` tag or the `p` tag? Also what is the purpose of this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see anything from you (trying first) so I will help you in what you should do.

```
<p class="more-content" style="display: block;">Am 25.10.2017 lädt das Netzwerk <a class="more-content-link" href="#" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">#Link</a>ückeLüneburg ein zur Veranstaltung
```

**Step1:** Your example is not properly closed, anyway since is Jquery you can add an ID to take the ID with JQUERY

Result

```
<p class="more-content" style="display: block;">Am 25.10.2017 lädt das Netzwerk <a class="more-content-link" href="#" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">#Link</a><span id="myText">ückeLüneburg ein zur Veranstaltung </span></p>
```

**Step2:** Grab it with Jquery (and the text inside)

```
let myText = $('#myText').text() // To take 'ückeLüneburg ein zur Veranstaltung'
```

**Step3**: Use `split` to split the string into substring

```
let result = myText.split(" "); // This will produce an array
```

Now your array will be like this `["ückeLüneburg", "ein", "zur" ,"Veranstaltung"]`

Next I hope you know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using jquery like this.But I think there is no sense in removing word like this.

First split the line where you want to remove first word.

Then use the `0th` word which is ückeLüneburg and replace it with blank string.Then set its content back as what you need.

```js
var p = $('p')[0];
console.log(p.childNodes[2].textContent.toString().trim().split(' ')[0])
p.childNodes[2].textContent=p.childNodes[2].textContent.toString().replace(p.childNodes[2].textContent.toString().trim().split(' ')[0],'')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="more-content" style="display: block;">
    Am 25.10.2017 lädt das Netzwerk
    <a class="more-content-link" href="#" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">#Link</a>
    ückeLüneburg ein zur Veranstaltung
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript/Jquery to achieve...
Get the Html of the p element, get indexes of "" and next space " " charcters.. remove the not required word but concatenating rest of the string..

```
txt = $("p.more-content").html();
startIndex = txt.indexOf("</a>") + 4; //4 is length of </a>
endIndex = txt.indexOf(" ",startIndex+1);
updatedtxt = txt.substring(0, startIndex) + txt.substring(endIndex);
$("p.more-content").html(updatedtxt);
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/LLf2me0k/)